# Move App to SD in Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, app2sd

There is no option in Samsung Galaxy Mega 5.8, Android version 4.2.2 as "Move to SD Card" in Application Manager.

Answer (score 1):

The other way of doing this is more simpler, the [blog](http://usmanafzal.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/use-adb-method-to-install-apps-or-move-installed-applications-to-sd-card-on-your-android-phone/) which was where I learnt this from.

`adb shell pm getInstallLocation`, the value returned is 0 is default.

- 0 is Auto, will by default Android OS will install it as it sees best.
- 1 is Internal, apps will get installed to the internal filesystem.
- 2 is External, apps will get installed to the external filesystem, by way of SD Card.

Now, to change that to external location

`adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2`, the changes will persist across reboots and any apps will get installed to the SDCard by default.

*Beware:* I am unaware if this will work in the newer later versions of Jellybean. As the latest I have is CM 10.1 Android 4.2 so the mileage may vary.

**Amendment:**

As per @Izzy's comment below, the newer Jellybean version *and probably will remain for later Android versions from that point onwards* the commands used above are, `adb shell pm get-install-location` and `adb shell pm set-install-location` respectively in place of the older commands as highlighted above. Reference found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: Comment from [Canoe](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/43943/canoe) (posted as answer and thus being removed): Be aware of a syntax change. On newer Android versions it's rather `pm get-install-location` and `pm set-install-location`. Reference (by Izzy): [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

Comment: @Izzy - cheers for the heads up, will fix it up! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [AppMgrIII](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en), its free, as there is no default option available.

Comment: This did not resolve http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61108/how-do-i-get-a-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-kids-to-preference-the-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

You have to root your device:

http://www.idroidspace.com/root-samsung-galaxy-mega-5-8-and-install-cwm-touch-recovery/

Then install the app in the sd memory and then (finally) you can unroot your device so to don't lose the warranty or the O.S. update