# How do I get a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Kids to preference the SD card?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-tab

My son's Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Kids edition is running low on space after I added several applications.

I added a micro SD card (external card) to compensate for storage.  I confirmed I was capable of standard Read-Write-Delete tasks against files on the external card from within the standard files app.

Unfortunately, I discovered that the system is unable to move applications to the external card (the option is simply never offered!).  I'm also having problems setting various applications (camera, music, etc.) to preference storing their data to the external card rather than the internal card.

Android version 4.1.2, Model number SM-T2105.

How can I best leverage using the external SD card?

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48885/move-app-to-sd-in-jelly-bean/54255#54255) which should answer your question, *I hope!*

Comment: Other Q&As helping you in your situation: [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) / [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29416/16575) / [High Frequented 'internal-storage' Questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage) (as that's where you want to "free up" space)

Comment: Thank you, @Izzy. Any idea why I can't transfer the applications to external SD card like any other Android system?  Heck, even my old Droid X used to allow it (where do you think I got the SD card from? :-) )

Comment: For that you'll have to ask Samsung. If they act like LG, they'll blame Android (saying "starting with ICS, this is no longer possible" – which of course is complete bull... ah, nonsense). But there might be tricks for that as well, see e.g. [How to move application to SD card in samsung galaxy s duos](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43357/16575): Also a Samsung device, having the very same problem. Another possible work-around involves executing `pm set-install-location 2` from either a terminal app or `adb shell`, as t0mm13b already suggested.