# How move applications from built-in memory to SD-card without root access?

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory, app2sd, sony-xperia

I have Sony Xperia M.
It has 4GB of built-in memory, however I see only 2GB)))

The fact of applications can be installed only in built-in memory upset me very much.
I do not play any hard games. Heavy one, I've installed, is 150MB program of off-line maps with 3 city and it occupies all of place((( Now I have a 16GB of free place on my SD-card and I get a message every minute, that it is not enough memory for android. It is very sad news.

I have moved or deleted from built-in memory everything I can.
Can I explain to my phone that sd-memory is exactly the same memory as a built-in?
Or somehow can I move one my heavy application to sd-card, keep it works?
Or what do you advice me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've just added two tags to your questions. Please check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) plus the [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), they hold the information you need to get started on this. Then please return and answer your own question if solved, or [edit] it and describe what you've tried and were you're stuck. Thanks!

Comment: All programs in the links, you gave me, need a root access. I want avoid it very much. So I started to brake. It is very sad, but manufacturer does not leave me any choice. Thanks.

Comment: The tag-wikis themselves give outlines, and in the case of app2sd explain the basic ideas. Have you checked e.g. the [questions tagged `app2sd`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app2sd?sort=frequent) for possible non-root solutions? I know they do exist, question is just which of them works with your device. See e.g. [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/10234/16575) ([newer syntax](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/42821/16575)), [Move App to SD in Jelly Bean](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/48885/16575).